# .htaccess makes url pretty but now shows no content on the page

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url, clean-urls

My urls currently look like this:

`http://www.example.com/test`

and they used to look like this:

`http://www.example.com/post.php?post=test`

That's great but my post.php page doesn't show any content anymore i.e. it doesn't show my blog post, title and time stamp.

My `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+post\.php\?post=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /post.php?post=/$1 [L]
```

and my post.php page looks like this:

```
<?php 
require("controller.php");
$post = $_GET['post'];
$rows = show_post($post);

    foreach($rows as $row): ?>

    <h1><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $row['title'] )?></h1>
    <p><?php echo $row['post'] ?></p>
    <p>Published on <?php echo $row['stamp'] ?></p>

    <?php endforeach; ?> 

    <p><a href="index.php">Return to home</a></p>
```

What am I doing wrong? This is doing my head in! Let me know if you need further info.

Comment: What if you try this code: `RewriteRule ^([^/\.]*)/*$ post.php?post=$1 [L]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a small error. Remove the backslash before $1:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /post.php?post=$1 [L]
```